# ArcMap 10.3 Display different extents in Layout view (same dataframe)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, layouts, data-frame

I have a Layer with around 100 rather small polygons that are quite far apart spatially. If i want to make a single map with them you can barely see the fill colour of the polygons. 
The solution i'm familiar with is to create multiple dataframes with each single dataframe showing a set of polygons that are close to each other.
However with this solution I would end up with about 8 Dataframes the problem with that being on one hand slowed performance but more importantly, whenever I want to change the symbology of my layer i have to do so in every dataframe?!

**Desired Solution:**

- Either a way to show different extents of the same dataframe in the Layout view
- Or a way to link dataframes so that a change of symbology in the original dataframe is simultaneously done in every copy of said dataframe.

Comment: If polygons too small, compute their centres and show points on a single frame

Answer (score 1):

just create bookmarks on your map view and in the layout you can jump from one to another selecting them.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Though i think this doesn't solve my problem, as I would like to have the different extents in the layout at the same time.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand the question correctly.
You can copy and paste your layout extents as many times as you want, and selecting one by one you can assign a different bookmark to each of them.

Comment: This still leaves me with the problem of having several data frames.

Comment: And since bookmarks only save extent but not the symbology this unfortunately doesn't help me either.